# How to integrate Facebook sdk to the windows store app using winjs

Tags: windows, winjs

Hi I want to integrate Facebook sdk to the windows store app using winjs .i got Facebook sdk for c# in nugget package.but did not find any thing for winjs.any suggestion will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a winjs library for facebook,listed in official facebook developers page.For more information please visit https://github.com/Thuzi/facebook-winjs-sdk